# Programmatically replicate CSS layout with PHP

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help me with this one.

I'm trying to transfer the layout of a PHP/SQL website currently using tables to CSS.
I already have the css working (thanks to Yahoo Grid Builder) but now I need to show it programmatically in my website after I have the info on an array (through `$row = dbFetchAssoc($result)`)

I guess the solution is to use `n%m` to catch the condition I need but I'm struggling with It.

The css I need to replicate is this one, the two `class="yui-g"` create a row and each `class="yui-u first"` and `class="yui-u"` create a cell in that row, so this code gives you a table with 2 rows and 4 columns. I want to show a new item of my array in each "Item N" (cell).

```
<div class="yui-g">
  <div class="yui-g first">
    <div class="yui-u first">Item 1</div>
    <div class="yui-u">Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="yui-g">
    <div class="yui-u first">Item 3</div>
    <div class="yui-u">Item 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="yui-g">
  <div class="yui-g first">
    <div class="yui-u first">Item 5</div>
    <div class="yui-u">Item 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="yui-g">
    <div class="yui-u first">Item 7</div>
    <div class="yui-u">Item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Why use CSS to create a fake table, when you can just use a table?

Comment: Using tables is fine if it is semantically correct, i.e. for displaying tabular data. It is not OK to use tables for layout (CSS should). I don't see why you wouldn't want to use a table for this.

Comment: I'm just looking to create a "tableless" layout, but maybe I have to reconsider It after your comments... Is It that wrong not wanting to use tables?

Comment: Tableless layouts are fine - but in situations where displaying tabular data as an HTML table makes more sense then do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general - HTML tables should be used to display tabular data, with CSS used to style those tables.

HTML + CSS should be used for layouts, rather than the old ways of using tables to position content.

Comment: If it makes semantic sense :-) Also dont forget to accept you chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `<table>` for tabular data** (data that you would store in a table).  Everything else should be using HTML with CSS.  From the looks of your code you should be using tables.